# JWPlayer not viewable in Qt5 QWebView

Tags: javascript, qt, qt5, jwplayer, qwebview

I tried to load html file with JWPlayer in QWebView but it won't show. It works in Chrome but not in QWebView, where is the problem?

HTML file:

```
<html>
<body>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://www.old.newton.ac.uk/js/jwplayer/jwplayer.js"></script>  

<div id="myvideo5">Loading the player...</div>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        jwplayer("myvideo5").setup({
            file: "http://download.wavetlan.com/SVV/Media/HTTP/H264/Talkinghead_Media/H264_test1_Talkinghead_mp4_480x360.mp4",
        });
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

My Qt code for QWebView looks like this:

```
ui->webView->load(QUrl("/home/debian/Desktop/video.html"));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like QWebView does not support HTML5 video.